# Companies that test foreign DNA for genealogical matters?

Tags: dna

Inspired by [another question](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2472/what-factors-should-i-consider-when-choosing-a-dna-testing-service), I got interested in companies that provide DNA tests for genealogy matters.

The problem is that the samples would be collected and submitted from Brazil, looking for ancestors from Italy, Czech and Poland.

And after having my DNA sequenced, where should I submit it or where could I find DNA from other people for possible matches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Family Tree DNA](http://www.familytreedna.com) is based in the U.S., but has customers worldwide -- they can and do ship DNA kits anywhere.  They also have resellers in Europe and the Middle East, which helps bring in the international samples.

Other U.S.-based companies only ship within the U.S. or have limited international reach.  For example, Ancestry.com's new [AncestryDNA](http://dna.ancestry.com) test is U.S.-only at the moment, and [23andMe](http://www.23andMe.com) ships to a [limited list of countries](https://customercare.23andme.com/entries/21262316-do-you-take-international-orders).

There are genetic genealogy companies outside the U.S., but the biggest ones are U.S.-based.

The [International Society of Genetic Genealogy (ISOGG)](http://www.isogg.org) has a [list of genetic genealogy companies](http://www.isogg.org/wiki/List_of_DNA_testing_companies) at their website.

All companies have their own databases, where you are compared to other customers of the company.  However, depending on what type of test you are doing, there are also external databases where you can upload your results for further comparison.  Some companies also allow uploading results from another company.

Disclaimer: I'm currently a consultant for FamilyTreeDNA, though I started as a customer first in 2005.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed above Family Tree DNA are your best option. They have by far the most international database. They also have lots of geographical projects where results can be compared with other people with ancestry from the same country or region. There is a list in the ISOGG Wiki:

http://www.isogg.org/wiki/Geographical_DNA_projects